# Facebook marketing api call, how to get all campaigns and report like power editor in api call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

In my main account i can see two ads account ids,

account one https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/act_1/campaigns   returns empty data in json

account one https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/act_2/campaigns  returns error 
 This Ads API call requires the user to be admin of the ad account. User is not admin on ad account

in power editor i have 4 campaigns running that are associated with account 2

next i have to get details that we can see in power editor like
advert_name, amount spend, clicks, impressions, Mobile app installs [1 Day After Viewing] Mobile app installs [28 Days After Clicking] etc i read their document but i am new to this, understood very little .

Answer (score 0):

Please read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/

You have to add the user whose token is used for the REST Call as an admin for the ad account in your facebook business explorer.

For creating your REST Call with all data you need, you might try the Graph API Explorer where you can add the fields you want to read.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer